# Including literal JSON content in Velocity (avoiding HTML escapes)

Tags: velocity, vtl

I'm trying to use the Velocity engine embedded in Atlassian's products (and exposed through com.atlassian.templaterenderer) to substitute a JSON value into a template.

In the template, this looks a bit like the following:

```
<script>
  foo = $foo
</script>
```

However, when I render the template with "foo" mapped to a string `["bar", "baz"]`, the output is the following:

```
<script>
  foo = [&quot;bar&quot;, &quot;baz&quot;]
</script>
```

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atlassian has an event handler which performs escaping on any variable with a name not ending with `WithHtml`.

Thus:

```
<script>
foo = $fooWithHtml
</script>
```

expands as desired.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a default behavior, looks like you have `EscapeHtmlReference` event handler  registered either in your `velocity.properties` or in java initialization. More details on event handlers [here](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Event_Handlers).